# Django perpetual 404s when visiting project directory URL

Tags: django, litespeed

I have a very strange problem with Django and OLS. I am using the OpenLitespeed Django one click install droplet on Digital Ocean. In both my custom app and the example app in the droplet, if I visit a URL that matches the django project directory (in the example app, this is /demo/), then any subsequent page visits give a 404 error, no matter what URL you do. To reproduce, I've spun up a completely clean install of the droplet, then do the following steps:

1. Go to / -> see "Hello world!" as expected
2. Go to /demo/ -> also see "Hello world!" even though this should be a 404, as this URL is not specified in the urls.py or anywhere else
3. Go back to / -> 404! It seems to be looking for /demo/demo/ which doesn't exist
4. Trying any other URL also results in a 404.

The only way to get back to the normal behavior is to restart the OLS process. Everything then functions as expected unless any URL that starts with the project directory name is visited, in which case the whole thing crashes and returns 404s again.

Any help that can be provided to try and further troubleshoot this or possible fixes is greatly appreciated!

Versions:
OLS 1.6.9
Django 2.2 and 3.0
Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the bug reporting. It's a bug of "virtual context settings for wsgi" and should already fixed on version 1.6.11. If it's not on the repository, you can run the following command to upgrade it.

```
/usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/lsup.sh -v 1.6.11
```

Best,
Eric